# Usages of JPA Native Query and IN SQL Statement

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

The code below have problem passing list of string as IN statement

```java
List<UserEntity> userEntities = repositoryTest.find("ABC,EFG");
```

I have tried passing in as List array but the spring JPA doesnt seem supporting it

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user tu " + " WHERE rgroup.code IN ( ? )", nativeQuery = true)
List<UserEntity> find(String ids);
```

I am expecting the List of UserEntity from find method above return entities with rgroup with the code of ABC and EFG

Comment: `?` placeholders are more of a JDBC thing, JPA uses named placeholders `:likeThis` instead. Have you tried using a named placeholder instead of a JDBC placeholder?

Comment: JonK , it works!